# Change Application Image/Appearance

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

How can I change this picture of my application?
Right now it's just the default image, but I just can't find a way to change it.

[image: My application isn't even running yet]

Edit: These are all the icons I have already set:

[image: icons set]

Comment: you have to reference an image as app icon in the [Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html).

Comment: @derHugo I have an Icon for my app already set.

Comment: well apparently not ;) I can not see any details of your configurations ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to reference an image as app icon in the [Player Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Icon).

[image]

and all images you require in

[image]

Note that the given image resolution has to match the required resolution.

And also the [Splash image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Splash)

---

Alternatively you can also configure them using the [`Package.appxmanifest` in VisualStudio](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/style/app-icons-and-logos#managing-app-icons-with-the-visual-studio-manifest-designer) before deploying or building the app package

---

**Note** I'm also pretty sure the ending e.g. `imageName.scale-200.png` is **mandatory** so check if your images are named correctly!

Comment: I think what I'm missing is the Windows Splash Image. Do you know if one of them is enough or if I need all of them?

Comment: afaik for hololens you only need the [Windows Holographic](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsWSA.html#Holographic) one. For the others `You can add up to seven different resolutions` Unity will automatically use the one closest to the needed resolution if you provided only one. Usually adding the `Default Icon` should be enough and the other icons should be generated (by Visual Studio) afaik.

Comment: I have now all icons, even a holographic splash screen but still no picture where I originally wanted it.

Comment: maybe also check [this](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-your-logos-and-splash-screens-right-for-mi) for more details on which icons are neccesarry .. the one you ask about should be one of those. **Note** I'm also pretty sure the ending e.g. `.scale-200.png` is mandatory so check if your images are named correctly

Comment: Oh I didn't pay attention to the file names, I'll try this tomorrow. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry for the late update, forgot to comment after I got it to work. Turns out the ending with `.scale-200.png` is the thing I didn't do, now it works just fine.